# How to deal with the `up-to-date` thing?

Tags: github, git-pull

How to deal with the `up-to-date` thing?

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
```

how to do with this one? 
the `up-to-date`.

Comment: Has the remote branch changed?

Comment: no :( i got problem in

 C:\Users\OJT\Java>git pull
Already up-to-date.

i dont know what to do after im sorry
im just a new bie

Comment: C:\Users\OJT\Java>git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 5bf1002 Okay :3
HEAD is now at 5bf1002 Okay :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your branch is up-to-date with '`origin/master`'.

That means your local branch and your upstream branch (the remote tracking branch origin/master which memorizes that last fetch from origin) are identical.

```
x--x--x--x (master, origin/master)
```

Try a `git fetch origin` to be sure.

- If it answer: "`Already up-to-date`", that means your branch is completely identical to what is on the upstream repo `origin`.
  You might have some local modification (that you should add and commit): *then* your status would change (stating that `master` is 1 commit ahead of `origin`)
- if it fetches some commit, then the status will state that master is *behind* `origin/master`:

  ```
             y--y (origin/master)
            /
  x--x--x--x (master)
  ```

A simple `git pull` would be enough (fetch + merge `origin/master` into `master`), but if you have local changes, stash them first (`git stash`, then `git stash pop` after the pull)

Comment: i got problem in
 C:\Users\OJT\Java>git pull Already up-to-date
     
C:\Users\OJT\Java>git stash Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 5bf1002 Okay :3 HEAD is now at 5bf1002 Okay :3

Comment: @okay do a `git stash pop` to get back your current modification. Note; the first `git stash` is supposed to be done *before* the `git pull`, not after.

Comment: No local changes to save
this is the message after i use git stash

Comment: @okay but what does `git stash pop` return? Do you see your modification back with a `git status` after having done a `git stash pop`?

Comment: Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (7349ecc0f4a8aadc86d35e331c419b7ad5d64a87)

Comment: @okay OK: your working tree is clean: you are good to go. You can start doing some modification, add, commit and push :)

Answer (score 0):

do you make :

> git add .

to add new files to your project
after :

> git commit -a

to commit all your change

next step

> git pull

to create pull request and merge the git with your repesitory

and to finish :

> git push

to push to the server.

Comment: i got problem in
 C:\Users\OJT\Java>git pull Already up-to-date
     
C:\Users\OJT\Java>git stash Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 5bf1002 Okay :3 HEAD is now at 5bf1002 Okay :3